# Передача данных в запущенный JAR

Tags: java

Есть два JAR файла:

1. Запускает через `ProcessBuilder`;
2. JAR с определенными параметрами.

В дальнейшем в процессе работы обоих файлов нужно передавать данные между ними в обе стороны. Раньше я делал всё это через сокет, поднимая сервер в первом и второй подсоединялся к нему. Сейчас задача стоит передавать данные не создавая сокетсервер. Пробовал рефлексией с первого прокинуть пайпы, но не вышло, второй не видит их.
Передавать данные нужно жавовских типов: инты стринги и арейлист<стрин>. Как можно их передавать имея в добавок управление через `ProcessBuilder`?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/RMI

Answer (score 4):

1. Самый быстрый способ - сокеты.
2. Или же можно использовать [RMI](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/RMI).
3. Ещё есть [JMS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Message_Service). Можно использовать какой-нибудь RabbitMQ или Apache ActiveMQ.
4. [JavaSpaces](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%B9).
5. Через базу данных.
6. Есть ещё топорный метод - общаться через файл на диске.

Comment: Ещё через имя файла можно )

Comment: Это всё не то, от сокетов нужно отказаться, в файл и базу тоже не вариант, это всё происходит на клиентской стороне и данные нужно хоть как то прятать (они и так шифрованы в сокетах да еще с SSL).

Answer (score 2):

А решение я нашел такое:

1 jar

```
package tests;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

public class AppFirst {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-cp", 
        "./bin", "tests.AppSecond");
    pb.directory(new File("."));
    pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
    Process proc = pb.start();

    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(
        proc.getOutputStream());
    ObjectInputStream oin = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        out.writeObject("Hello world " + i);
        out.flush();
        if (oin == null) {
            oin = new ObjectInputStream(proc.getInputStream());
        }
        String s = (String)oin.readObject();
        System.out.println(s);
    }
    out.writeObject("Stop");
    out.flush();

    proc.waitFor();
}
}
```

2 jar

```
package tests;

import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

public class AppSecond {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ObjectInputStream oin = null;
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(System.out);
    while (true) {
        if (oin == null) {
            oin = new ObjectInputStream(System.in);
        }
        String s = (String)oin.readObject();
        if ("Stop".equals(s)) {
            break;
        }
        out.writeObject("Received: " + s);
        out.flush();
    }
}
}
```

Проверил аррейлисты пролазиют отлично и не мешают в выводе.

Comment: И даже в этом случае очень просто перехватить данные, если от сокетов отказались по этой причине.

Comment: перехват уже не страшен, мало того что там всё шифрованное + неизвестные объекты передаются + жарники пройдены стрингером + шифрование привязано к времени и подменить его уже будет невозможно.